# App Engine: Unable to Change Authentication Type

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication

I have a google app engine app. It's Authentication Type is currently `Federated Login`... but I would like to change it to `Google Accounts` so I can use the `remote_api`.

However, the `Authentication Type` select box is disabled in both the new console and the old console.

I know you can't change the authentication type to/from Domain authentication, but I have never used that.

Is there a reason it is disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google account I was using only had `developer` permissions.

As soon as I logged into the console using an `owner` account I was able to change it!